# Seperate domains for SSL & NonSSL pages under fb app

Tags: facebook

I had created one Facebook app, which have some pages on SSL & some pages on non-SSL, and they both have separate domains, in this case when i access the SSL page, it goes directly on server page (outside from Facebook), instead of coming under iframe in fb app.. Are we can't able to use multiple domain, as in Facebook app settings, for domain settings we have only one field (Site Domain) so in this field which domain value I'm suppose to enter?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook just announced support for multiple domains per application in their [latest blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/), so you can now enter both url's in the app domain field on your app settings page.